# Moving text file from one folder to another folder using python in windows

Tags: python

I am trying to move text files from one folder to another by reading a path from a csv file. First I create the target folder in which I want to move my files from the existing folder. I read the existing folder path from csv file. I am working on a Windows platform.

This is my code :

```
import os
import csv
import shutil

#csv_filename = raw_input('Enter CSV filename:')
with open('insurance_sample.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    header = next(readCSV)
    count = 0
    for row in readCSV:
        dirname = "/".join(('Sorted_Program',row[1],row[4],row[3],row[7]))
        #if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            #os.makedirs(dirname)
        path = row[10] 
        moveto = dirname
        print path
        print moveto
        print os.path.isfile(path)
        files = os.listdir(path)
        print files
        files.sort()
        for f in files:
            src = path + f
            dst = moveto + f
        break
```

I am getting this error after running the code:

```
C:\Users\Ashwin\Desktop\p\newDir\Archives\Beta\A380_1
Sorted_Program/A380/AFR/69/Flight_Test
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ashwin\Desktop\p\newDir\sar.py", line 19, in <module>
    files = os.listdir(path)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Ashwin\\Desktop\\p\\newDir\\Archives\\Beta\\A380_1/*.*
```

Please let me know if the question is still confusing and I will try to explain in more detail.

Comment: Yes. The thing is file exists in the specified path.

Comment: Did you make sure the path exists?

Comment: `*.*` isnt a filename. If you're trying to grab all files, you have to do that differently

Comment: Yes I am trying to grab all the files

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there are two issues here:

1. You are creating a directory reference with `/` whereas windows directories require `\`
2. Your code does not prefix the new directory structure with `\`

Try the following modification:

```
dirname = "\\" + "\\".join(('Sorted_Program',row[1],row[4],row[3],row[7]))
```

Comment: Why are you adding two   "\\" + "\\"  . Because when I am using two I cannot create folder chain. But when I am using one "\\"  I am able to create folder chain.                                                                          This also does not solve previous problem

Comment: Use os.path.join to be safest. In any case I had no problem with '/' inwindows.

Comment: @Ash912T So windows by default relies on the "\" but in Python "\" is also an escape character, so to write backslash to a string, you have to escape it...with another backslash (hence the "\\"). The issue I see with your code is that you end up generating a directory reference that has a space in it because Python .join does not prepend the join character (e.g. `"/".join(["a","b"])` gives `"a/b"` not `"/a/b"`. Would you mind letting me know what the created directory path is now?

Comment: C:\Users\Ashwin\Desktop\p\newDir\Archives\Beta\A380_1                              This is the actual directory path

Comment: Hey @Ash912T, sorry it seems I misunderstood the problem you were having! My bad. Having looked at it again, are you absolutely certain the directory exists, and your script has the right permissions to access etc? That's the only error that would make sense here in my experience. Unfortunately I don't actively develop on a windows env anymore so not sure how much further help I can be here. Apologies.